# Accessing a signal in both structural and behavioural architecture

Tags: architecture, signals, vhdl, counter

I have defined the structural architecture of a module e.g.

```
architecture structural of my_entity is
    signal counter : integer := 0;
    begin
        MODULE port map(......count => counter.....); --this is an inout port
end structural;
```

I would like to implement a counter which is incremented based on a change in an input signal `signalIn` to `my_entity`, and have this counter value transferred to `MODULE`.

Is there a way I can increment this `counter` signal in a behavioural architecture of `my_entity`? For example

```
architecture Behavioural of my_entity is
    begin
        process(signalIn)
            begin
                counter <= counter + 1;
        end process;
end Behavioural;
```

Of course, within this behavioural architecture the `counter` is reported undeclared. How might I get around this?

Comment: There is no apparent declaration for signal counter in the architecture behavioral. Copy the declaration from the architecture structural to behavioral.  Also note that your process will increment counter on any event on `signalIn`, and even if intended this behavior is not synthesis eligible.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I assume that if I declared it again in behavioural then it would be a new signal and not affecting the one being transferred to `MODULE`. Is there a way I can increment that signal upon a change to `signalIn`?

Comment: How could it effect the instantiation of `MODULE`?  It's in a different architecture. "More than one architecture body may exist corresponding to a given entity declaration. Each declares a different body with the same interface; thus,each together with the entity declaration represents a different design entity with the same interface. "

Comment: This is what my original question is referring to. How can I increment a counter which is transferred to `MODULE`? I'm thinking I may have to make a new entity specifically for this.

Comment: Your question appears both unclear and lacking in [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - the abstract code you displayed does not convey the idea.  Instantiate `MODULE` in an architecture that also contains a process with a counter that increments a declared signals `counter`.  You could move the process (fixed presumably for synthesis) from the second architecture to the first (copy the first to a third and copy the process to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question while showing a declaration in one architecture for `counter` doesn't show a declaration for signal `inSignal` (it's a signal because it shows up in the sensitivity list of a process). Nor do you show the component declaration for `MODULE`.

```
my_enity is
end entity;

architecture structural of my_entity is
    signal counter: integer := 0;
begin
UNLABELLED_COMPONENT_INSTANTIATION:  -- presuming count is declared mode in
   MODULE port map(......count => counter.....); --this is an inout port
UNLABELLED_PROCESS:
    process (inSignal)
    begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
end architecture structural;
```

You can either use a process to operate counter (noting it's not shown in a form that can readily be synthesized) or a separate component instantation of a ***different*** entity architecture pair implementing the counter.

```
architecture pure_structural of my_entity is
    signal counter: integer := 0;
begin
UNLABELLED_COMPONENT_INSTANTIATION:  -- presuming count is declared mode in
   MODULE port map(......count => counter.....); --this is an inout port

COUNTER_COMPONENT:

    SOME_COUNTER port map (trigger => signalIn, count => counter);

-- where in this case count is mode out

end architecture pure_structural;
```

Comment: So the solution here is to combine behavioural and structural bodies. Thank you for your help.

Comment: At the simulation level everything is behavioral. Structural general refers to describing a design in terms of a interconnected hierarchy comprised of instantiated entity/architecture pairs.  Every concurrent statement is devolved into a process statement or combination of process statements and block statements providing hierarchy for simulation (and synthesis). Function calls are expression, procedure calls are statements (either sequential or concurrent, the latter devolved into processes).